# Google Search API find keywords

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I go about searching for the number of times a key word appears in a google search result within python?
I've been reading through the google documentation but can't find anything related to this.
For example, if I searched up "Mt. Everest", I'd like to count how many times that word appeared in website titles as well as the little snip-bits below them.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We prefer that you show us examples of code you worked on to get closer to the solution. A great way to do this is to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. If your question is more general, perhaps Googling a bit more will help you narrow down a solution path for you. Good luck!